# erlang - exception error: no function clause matching

Tags: function, erlang, pattern-matching

I've created a `concatenate/1` function, which should concatenate a list of lists and atoms:

```
concatenate(L)->                             
    concatenate(L,[]).                       


concatenate([],R)->                          
    reverse(R);                                       
concatenate([H|T],R) when is_atom(H) ->      
    concatenate(T,[H|R]);                    
concatenate([[]|L],R)->                      
    concatenate(L,R);                        
concatenate([[H|T]|L],R)->                   
    concatenate([T|L],[H|R]).
```

However I get the error:

```
15> ml:concatenate([[1,2],4,[3,4,5],[5,6]]).
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    ml:concatenate([4,[3,4,5],[5,6]],[2,1]) (ml.erl, line 27)
```

which I believe *should* match, because of the second `concatenate/2` clause.

May I ask, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There are two orthogonal issues braided together here: list formation and conditional checking. To arrive at a clean, more Erlangish solution we need to understand more about the problem from a higher level. IOW, it appears you have an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second clause you are using `when is_atom(H)` guard, which fails to match clause (because `H` in this case is number). Change it to `when is_number(H)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll adapt your solution to this case in an answer below

Answer (score 1):

Following the reasoning in Viacheslav Kovalev's answer, given that I want to handle atoms and numbers here, I have come up with the following solution:

```
concatenate([],R)->
    R;
concatenate([H|T],R) when not(is_list(H)) ->
    reverse(concatenate(T,[H|R]));
concatenate([[]|L],R)->
    concatenate(L,R);
concatenate([[H|T]|L],R)->
    concatenate([T|L],[H|R]).
```